# Как сделать, чтобы приложение понимало: устройство планшет или мобильник?

Tags: java, android

Я хочу сделать функцию на своём приложении, которое будет знать, это планшет или мобильник.

Чтобы если это планшет, он в `setContentView(R.layout.movie_activity);` поменял на `movie_activity2`.

Comment: Насколько мне помнится, в *Android Studio* стандартный шаблон с активити включает разделение разметки смартфон\планшет  - однопанельный интерфейс\двухпанельный. Но вы можете сделать любые свои различия в разметке по этому шаблону.

Comment: а зачем это вообще надо?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

*Вы не в том направлении рассуждаете*. Дело в том, рискну предположить, что вам нужно показывать контент, который по разному располагается на разных по величине устройствах.

Для этого есть разные  квалификаторы для макетов - (*layout-mdpi, layout-hdpi, layout-small* и д.р.). Для планшета нужно указать следующую квалификатор - *layout-w600dp* (с размером можно поиграться).

Раз вы задумали разные *layout*-ы, то предположу они отличаются не только компановкой, но и контентом. На пример на планшете есть доп. вьюхи с айдишниками, это тоже решается при помощи проверок в коде или специальной вьюхи - ViewStub.

Comment: Гугл называет их не локали а квалификаторы

Comment: уже поправил. =)